# Changed RAM and now my system is malfunctioning

Tags: upgrade, hardware, ram, thinkpad

I have a problem with a new RAM that I bought.
My system is a Thinkpad T410 with Debian 10 stable with 2+2GB of RAM.
Today I replaced a 2GB board with a 8GB.
I checked with htop my total amount of RAM and it's correct (9.6GB) but when my pc is stressed (lot of programs open and CPU under stress too) the system suddenly reboots.
This is the new RAM that I bought:

https://www.amazon.it/Timetec-PC3-12800-Unbuffered-Computer-Portatile/dp/B0145WDNI4/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=ram+thinkpad+8gb&qid=1602259408&sr=8-1

This computer used to work perfectly until now, so I'm almost sure that's a RAM problem, does anyone know how to fix this? I'm not an expert in changing hardware.

Comment: This isn't a U&L problem as much as a system troubleshooting problem.  Step one after "I changed a thing and now it's broken" is to change it _back_ and see if the problem goes away.  If it does, the problem is most likely the thing you changed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic for U&L - try Server Fault perhaps?

Comment: You can also try `memtest`. It's a search engine away.

Comment: i know it's a memory problem, but since i'm under linux can you give me some tips to check if there are some os conflicts with the rams? the RAM (the piece of hardware) could be working and this could be a OS problem.

Comment: Did you use anti-static protection when you changed the RAM?

Comment: no, i installed it as is , without tapes or anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave a solution for anyone that will have my same problem.
In my case I was trying to install a 8+2 GB RAM with the 8 GB at 1600 Mhz.
My T410 only supports 2,4,8 GB of a single RAM for a maximum of 8GB in total.
And as it's not enough, T410 only supports 1066 Mhz and this could cause conflicts as well.

Solution: check Frequency, Max RAM and single RAM  of your computer before buying a new RAM.

If you don't know your RAM specs you can use `dmidecode -t17` to print them in the terminal